# Bound on product of two real numbers within intervals

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

Given $a,b, c, d, \delta  \in \mathbb{R}$, $\delta > 0$, such that $|a-c| \leq \delta$ and $|b-d| \leq \delta$, I want to construct a bound on $|ab-cd|$ in terms of $c,d$ and $\delta$.

I proceeded in the following way:

Given the extremes of the intervals for $a$ and $b$,  $\{c-\delta, c+\delta, d-\delta, d+\delta\}$, then

$$
\begin{align*}
|ab-cd| &\leq \max \{ \begin{aligned}[t]
    &|cd-(c-\delta)(d-\delta)|, \\
    &|cd-(c-\delta)(d+\delta)|, \\
    &|cd-(c+\delta)(d-\delta)|, \\
    &|cd-(c+\delta)(d+\delta)|\} 
    \end{aligned} \\
    &\leq \max\{|\pm c\delta \pm d\delta \pm \delta^2|\} \\
    &\leq |c|\delta + |d|\delta +  \delta^2\\
\end{align*}
$$
where the last step comes from the triangle inequality.

Is this a valid bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bound you have is valid. There is actually a standard trick that would give you the same bound. That is, adding and subtracting something convenient.

\begin{align*} |ab - cd| &= |ab - cb + cb - cd| \\
                         &= |(a-c)b + c(b-d)| \\
                         &= |a-c||b| + |c||b-d| \\
                         &\le \delta(|d|+\delta) + |c|\delta \\
                         &= (|c|+|d|)\delta + \delta^2.
\end{align*}

We can see that this bound is tight as follows. Let $c = d = 1$ and let $a = b = 1+\delta$. Then

$$ |ab - cd| = |1+\delta^2 +2\delta - 1| = 2\delta + \delta^2 = (|c|+|d|)\delta + \delta^2. $$